# Invitees not getting email notification of the meeting (event)

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar

I created an event on iPhone (6.x) by tapping the plus sign on my icloud calender with two users having gmail email addresses. The email invitation has not gone out even after 15 mins now. Am I doing something wrong here? How can I resend the notification emails if there is such a way.

Comment: When you say that "the email invitation has not gone out", do you mean that you don't see something in your sent mail, or that your two recipients report that they haven't received the invitation yet?

Comment: Both. I checked the sent mail folder on iPhone - its not there. I have confirmed with recipients and they have not received it yet.

Comment: Your question might be a duplicate of this one:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27449/icloud-calendar-not-sending-invites

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37242?hl=en):

Change your notification settings

1. Open the Google Calendar app Google Calendar app icon.
2. In the top left, touch Menu > Settings.
3. Choose one of your calendars, like Events.
4. To change or remove a notification, touch it or touch Add another notification.