# How do I send invitations for Calendar events with locations?

Tags: icloud, calendar, bug

If a Calendar event has a location associated with it, no invitations are ever sent to any of the invitees. In fact, once a location is added to an event, no subsequent updates about changes to the event are ever sent to any invitees (including the addition of the location).

This failure is silent. No warning is given, the invitees are simply never informed of the event at all. This happens regardless of whether the invitees have iCloud addresses or not (in most cases, for me, all invitees are iCloud users).

I con reproduce this 100% of the time on both macOS and iOS. This error suddenly appeared recently, and since then I've learned from several friends that they have experienced the same problem.

How do I send invitations to events with locations from Calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a known bug. Apple Support's recommendation is (astonishingly) simply:

> Do not add a location to events you plan to invite people to.

Apple is "working on it as we speak".

Comment: The error persists in 10.12.3 and appears to behave as follows: invitations to events from Calendar containing (A) nothing but a name are sent quickly; (B) just a note are sent quickly; (C) a URL may or may not get sent, but it can take up to 24 hours;(D) are never sent at all.

Comment: Update: Now, some invitations with events eventually do arrive at the recipient, but (1) they typically only arrive in e-mail (even to iCloud users) and not in Calendar, and (2) accepting the event notifies me (the sender) but does not typically (though does sometimes) add the accepted event to the recipient's calendar. Thus (in addition to it now being laborious to accept an invitation, in the cases when an invitations is indeed sent) it is often the case that I think my invitee has the event scheduled, but they won't have it in their calendar!

Comment: This is arguably even worse than the original manifestation of this bug.

Comment: Update: In addition to (1) & (2) above: (3) when a recipient gets e-mail on an iOS device, there's no option to manually add the even to their calendar and (4) when I am notified of an acceptance of an invitation in Calendar (on macOS) and click OK it takes several hours for my acknowledgment to remove the notification.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered I have this same problem.  But in my case, while it started with not being able to send invites when there was an address, now it will not send invites at all regardless of whether there is an address.  A have Apple support working on this at the engineer level.  I am running Yosemite and found the problem occurs whether I create an event in the Mac OS Calendar App or log in to iCloud and create event there.  The senior tech advisor had be go though these steps:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204598

I offer this in case it might help your situation (it did not help mine).

Comment: Those steps aren't going to be helpful (it's not surprising that they didn't help you; I think they're misleading you): the issue is on Apple's end. They need to fix it.

Comment: I am sure you are right (in fact I said it did not help).  If it is a known issue (and it sounds like it is) then when you call Apple, they should be honest and just tell you that.  I can live with an honest answer, but trying to hide the fact they have a server issue is something I don't like. Just be honest Apple!

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the Calendar app and navigate to the date on which you would like to create an event.Tap the + icon in the upper-right corner. There, you’ll be able to name your event, as well as add a location if you'd like.
2. Then you can designate start and end times for your event, as well as add any notes for your invitees to see. You can also choose which of your Calendars the event will go in.
3. (If you can't see the Invitees tab, go to Settings, iCloud, and make sure Calendar is turned on. If you're still not seeing the Invitees tab, make sure you’re putting the event in one of your iCloud calendars.)
4. Tapping the Invitees tab will allow you to choose individuals from your contacts to invite, provided you have their email address in their contact card. The Invitees tab will then be updated to show how many people you've invited.

Comment: This is just the instructions for creating an event. The issue here is that no invitations are ever sent for any (correctly created or edited) events if they have a location associated.