# Calendar sharing invites are not sent

Tags: ios, icloud, calendar

I’m on an iPhone 11. I’m trying to **share an iCloud calendar** with other iCloud Users.

When I type in their accounts, invitations are not sent (or received) and each invitation is stuck in a pending state.

Any idea on how to fix this?

**Edit**: same problem happens if I try to share a calendar with the iCloud web interface

**Edit**: I cannnot receive sharing invitations as well

I'm using a yahoo account for iCloud

Comment: Have you checked this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27449/icloud-calendar-not-sending-invites

Comment: yes, I tries that option but things did not change. Cannot figure out what is happening.

Comment: Could it be related to the fact that my iCloud account uses a yahoo email address?

Comment: I am sure you have done this, but asking to confirm, did you check this: Besides "Invitations" select Email To (Use this option if your primary calendar is not iCloud).

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing seems changing