# Use iCloud calendar and contacts with non-Apple devices

Tags: icloud, calendar, caldav

A friend wants to sync his calendar (also his contacts if possible) with a non-iPhone device.

Is there a way to connect a device to iCloud via Exchange or CalDav. If so where could the specific parameters like servers and ports be found?

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27434/how-to-use-smtp-and-imap-with-icloud-email

Comment: @patrix I am more looking for a solution to include the calendar and contacts, rather than using eMail via SMTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a way to do this that may help your friend.  My setup does what you're describing.

I use Microsoft Exchange for work and Gmail for everything else.  I sync my iCal with Google calendar, Addressbook with Google contacts and use mail.app for all emails.  I use 4 devices and all of them have the same contacts and calendar information.

Since Addressbook and iCal have my current information, any non-iPhone device with access to Google calendar and contacts could use what I have on my Macs.  The non-iPhone device will need to be capable of syncing with Google calendar and contacts and most apps today have that functionality.

I also have a Comcast account that meshes fine with this setup since mail.app uses Addressbook and iCal instead of Comcast's contacts and calendar.  I sync everything by using the sync icon in the menu bar several times a week.  My setup includes an iPhone, iPad, Imac and MBP.

I'm researching iCloud to backup my Addressbook and contacts as well but I'm not in a rush since this setup performed reliably for the last 4 years.

Comment: Currently Google Calendar is not an option for him. I am looking for a solution to connect his device to iCloud.

Comment: What kind of device does he use?

Comment: He would like to use a Windows Phone

Comment: @Besi.  Here's a recent article that discusses windows options.  I've had no experience with the app discussed in the article but wanted t pass it along.  http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/242401/syncing_icloud_with_windows_and_outlook.html

Comment: This Preferences app seems to be what my friend needs. He can sync it to outlook and then surely from there to his Windows Phone. Thanks a lot!